# Why does my route "select" get turned into a <select> element in my handlebars template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm in the process of upgrading to Ember 1.9.1 and Handlebars 2.0, and for some bizarre reason, now I can't have a route & template named "select" because it gets rendered as a `<select>` element.

When I change the name to "selection" it works as expected.

Any idea why this is happening or any workarounds? I'd rather not adjust the URLs of my application because of this bug/feature.

Comment: Well select is now registered on the container. It may be the reason it affects ur code. You can check the deprecation docs for more info. Maybe you can try unregistering the select component with this.container.unregister('view:select');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @blessenm stated in the comment, your view is conflicting with the [select component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html). Since you don't want to change your routes to take another name, one alternative is to change the template name and override the [Route#renderTemplate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) to use the new name, so your urls will keep intact:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myselect">
  My template
</script>

App.SelectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('myselect');
  }
});
```

Live sample in http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tiyudazano/1/edit

Comment: Ah. Great. Worked perfectly. So it seems it's limited to the template name, and not the route url or the route name and controller name. A much simpler solution than I was fearing.